# Searching through a list of 100,000 elements as fast as possible in C#

Tags: c#, list, search, in-memory

I will soon have the need to repeatedly search through a list (about every 15s) of about 100,000 elements as fast as possible using C# looking for elements that have specific values. Would searching a List with Linq for elements (where 3-4 fields have specific values) be faster than using for example, an in-memory SQLite database? Is there a better option available?

I wouldn't mind recreating the database upon every program execution, so reading data in from a CSV file would be acceptable.

The dataset will be a window from a stream of data, subsequently, the list will gradually change, with one record being removed from the start of the list, and one more added to the end every 15s.

What options do I have?

Comment: Can the list be sorted?

Comment: Do you need to search once or repeatedly?

Comment: Repeated searches will be necessary and @crush I'm not sure what you mean about sorting the list?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a loaded question...how often will your 100,000 elements change? daily, hourly, etc...You need to consider if it is necessary to get an up to date dataset from your source that needs to be searched from.

Comment: If you are able to sort your list, then you could benefit from a binary search as opposed to a straight linear search. That could reduce your lookup time significantly. Also, if you know that certain records will be accessed more often, you can move them to the front of the list, so that a linear search would not have to go so far to find them. That is why it is important to know if sorting is an option for you. You could also look into using a hashtable, and computing a hash/key based on the value that will be used for lookup - would give you instantaneous lookups, but not always practical.

Comment: @crush ahh, no it isn't possible to sort the list in advance.

Comment: @crush binary search is O(Log(N)) a Dictionary/HashSet search is O(1)

Comment: Well, it sounds like the order of the list matters, so a HashSet won't work either. Looks like he's stuck with a straight linear search. If you have the option of using an in-memory SQLite database, though, that tells me that you have the option of creating indices. You could create a secondary HashSet or sorted list that points to the original, and use this secondary list only for lookups.

Comment: @Dave dataset will be a 'window' of 100k elements from a stream of data. one element will be pushed off the start, and another added to the end every 15s or so. I'll update the q.

Comment: In addition, Hardware, software also play a role but in a bigger picture, in memory operations often provide the best performance.

Comment: If you are adding/removing from the list that quickly, then a database like SQLite would be constantly rebuilding indexes - which could slow it down quite a bit as well. Of course, building an index on 100k records every 15s really isn't that intensive.

Comment: Can you put some quantification with "as fast as possible"? What is acceptable?

Comment: @crush if I were to go through the trouble of creating a secondary hashset as a 'key lookup' list, then I may as well use an in-memory database surely?

Comment: That's what an in-memory database is essentially, with added overhead.

Comment: @Dave yes, I'm assuming 100k elements won't be that memory intensive, so forcing the data to be stored on disk seems a severe bottleneck

Comment: @MK.Price Not really, no.  I use HashSets/Dictionaries all the time.  I almost never need to use an in-memory database.

Comment: You basically have a queue, and you want to be able to search that queue as quickly as possible. Without creating indexes (what you'd use a second HashSet for), your only option is a linear search.

Comment: @crush "as fast as possible" so as not to be a bottleneck in the system. I'll be using the data for further calculations. I know disk-based sqlite can be relatively slow

Comment: @crush i would need an "index" list for each key that i want to search on, right?

Comment: As items were added to the queue, you'd also have to compute a hash, and insert them into the HashSet with a pointer to the element that is in the queue. Likewise, you'd also probably want to drop them from the HashSet when they were popped from the queue...that's essentially what an in-memory database would do. It would just do it transparently for you.

Comment: Interesting. Would this allow me to retrieve multiple elements where the value of a field is within a specific range?

Comment: @Servy do you know of any online examples that allow searching for multiple records where element values are within a specific range?

Comment: I think you should give SQLite a try, and see if you are bottlenecking, to be honest. You might be prematurely optimizing here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll do that for now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper library named IndexedList, you can download it from http://indexedlist.codeplex.com/ With this library you can add indexes on any field(s) of your object then perform fast searches in your list. Default index implementation uses Dictionary for storing index data, you can change it too. I have created this library for my own projects then i published that as an open source project newly. I will be happy to hear your feedback about this library.